# How to see my Compute Engine app in my browser?

Tags: node.js, angular, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a virtual machine on Compute Engine of Google Cloud and I want to host my project made in Node and Angular on that virtual machine. I installed Node on the server and cloned my project from Git, its working perfectly.

My question is, how do I bring that project in the browser?

Comment: you should share more info if you are looking for an answer

Answer (score 1):

You should: `npm run build`. After that you could find dist folder with your project and copy content of this folder to  any static web server (GitHub pages and etc)
[Additional info](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

Comment: that is not what I asked. :(

Answer (score 0):

As Rajesh said in a previous answer, your question is a bit ambiguous. I think that maybe what you are asking is for a way to allow http/https traffic to your Google Compute Engine instance. Please feel free to correct me if I’m wrong.

If my assumption is correct, you need two things here. The first one is a [public IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) for your instance and the second is create firewall rules to [allow this kind of traffic](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#externalhttpconnection) from internet to your instance.